# Flask y MogoDB - Obtener y pintar en pantalla imágenes almacenadas en mongoDB (fs.files)

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

Estoy creando una app con Flask y PyMongo, donde almaceno imágenes en mongoDB. Me gustaría saber como pintarlas en pantalla; para ello utilizo jinja2. Mi código es el siguiente:

Las imágenes se obtienen de un formulario; ésta es la ruta para almacenar la imágenes en la base de datos:

```
@app.route('/add_image', methods = ['POST'])
def add_image():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['image_file']
        image_file_name = secure_filename(file.filename)
        mongo.save_file(image_file_name, request.files['image_file'])
```

De la siguiente forma es como se almacenan las imágenes en mongoDB en fs.files:

```
_id: ObjectId(611d80182ccc9db2ffbe258f)
filename: "adrian-Xft-JdC-Jbc-unsplash.jpg"
contentType:"image/jpeg"
md5: "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
chunkSize: 261120
length:0
uploadDate: 2021-08-18T21:48:10.514+00:00
```

Comment: Lo estas guardando como un tipo blobl, verdad?

Comment: En sí lo almaceno tal cual está en el código presentado, seguí la documentación de Flask_PyMongo

Comment: Pero como tal es un blob

Comment: el método `mongo.send_file(filename)` retorna la imagen

Comment: Excelente, ¿pero cómo podría mostrarlas en pantalla?

Comment: supongo que mandando la variable al template

Comment: Como tal, se pasa la variable al template, pero al establecerla lo que indica en pantalla es lo siguiente <Response streamed [200 OK]>, no la imagen.