# Flask y PyMongo - Pintar en pantalla imagen almacenada como tipo blob

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Estoy creando una app en la cual utilizp Flask, MongoDB y PyMongo, donde almaceno, las imágenes como dato de tipo blob en MongoDB, exactamente son guardadas en fs.files; me gustaría saber cómo pintar dichas imágenes, para ello utilizo jinja2.

Las imágenes se almacenan de la siguiente forma:

```
_id: ObjectId(611d80182ccc9db2ffbe258f)
filename: "adrian-Xft-JdC-Jbc-unsplash.jpg"
contentType:"image/jpeg"
md5: "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
chunkSize: 261120
length:0
uploadDate: 2021-08-18T21:48:10.514+00:00
```

Comment: Una sola pregunta es suficiente :)

Comment: Hasta ahora lo se hacer guardando las imágenes como base64, si pudieras poner un codigo que permita reproducir tu situación, intentaría ver si te puedo ayudar.

Comment: A propósito, te has duplicado la pregunta: [ver la misma pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/477870/flask-y-mogodb-obtener-y-pintar-en-pantalla-im%c3%a1genes-almacenadas-en-mongodb-f)

Comment: Muchas gracias, podrías revisar la siguiente pregunta, por favor, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/477933/flask-y-mongodb-recuperar-archivos-de-mongo-db, allí establezco el código que escribí para subir las imágenes a mongoDB y posteriormente retornarlas, sin embargo no son pintadas en pantalla, me gustaría saber como realizarlo.