# Flask y MongoDB - Recuperar archivos de mongo DB

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

Estoy creando una app con Flask, en la cual ya he escrito el código necesario para agregar archivos a una base de datos en mongoDB y a su vez recuperarlos, en éste caso los archivos son imágenes, y al establecer la ruta en la etiqueta  para recuperar las imágenes, no se muestran en pantalla. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html', data = data_list)

@app.route('/add_image', methods = ['POST'])
def add_image():
    file = request.files['image_file']
    image_file_name = secure_filename(file.filename)
    mongo.save_file(image_file_name, request.files['image_file'])

    pictures.insert({
        'file_name': image_file_name
    })   
    return redirect('/') //Ésta ruta redirige al inicio de la app
    
// Ésta es la ruta con la cual intento obtener las imágenes, sin embargo no no se muestran en pantalla
@app.route('/get_image/<filename>')
def get_image(filename):
    return mongo.send_file(filename)
```

Y en ésta parte es donde se procede a mostrar las imágenes con la ruta correspondiente, sin embrago, no se pintan las imágenes.

```
{% for doc in data %}
<img src="{{url_for('get_image', filename = doc.file_name)}}" alt="{{doc.file_name}}">
{% endfor %}
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría saber cómo se podría realizar. Muchas gracias